# Weird icons for JPG and RAR files in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

Icons of my jpg and rar files are presented by weird icon. [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k30K1.jpg). What’s the problem?

[image]

Comment: There is an edit for the Windows version, that was probably made by you. Just so you're aware, you can freely edit your own posts, comment within your own thread, and accept an answer, but for your protection, it must be done under the original user account.  It's no big deal if you popped back in to make a change without logging in.  But if you are unable to log in, you won't be able to interact on your thread.  I rejected the edit to ensure that you can.  If you can't, create a new ID and we can get them merged.  If you can, comment here and the edit will get approved or you can re-enter it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you due to an installation of PhotoStage by NCH. I can say that the program set all kind of file associations, but in a wrong and buggy way. To restore your icons back to normal (your own programs association, not windows default), you have to search on regedit for this string

```
    %SystemRoot%\SysWow64\shell32.dll,19
```

Note: this string corresponds to the icon that was showing in my specific case, so the last number (it's an index) could be different. Try to localize a string for a file association that you know is wrong and take the index value from there. If I remember correctly, the icon showing on my end was the pdf one. Everything showed the PDF File icon.

Delete every value that contains that string, and "DefaultIcon" is the name of the keys containing it.

Just do it with every string you can find, then, restart explorer.exe or reboot your computer. Everything should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem possibly could be a virus infection, or perhaps you need to rebuild the icon cache (you can do that with a program). If you suspect the problem to be a virus infection you can check your computer for viruses/malware with Malwarebytes AntiMalware, and also look for Adware with [this program (AdwCleaner)](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/).

A program you use can also have changed the icon for those files: for change the icon and the associated program to open those files, set a custom program to always open the JPEG files (do the same with RAR files). For that do this:

1. Right click the file and look for an option called "Open with..."
2. Choose the program you want to always open those files and check the option "Use the selected program for open this kind of files" and accept.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you either installed, or (accidentally) manually configured, some other program to associate with those file types. When a program is associated with a file type, it will usually change the file's icon. A program could also have directly changed the icon without messing with the file association, but that's uncommon. Either way, it's a pretty simple registry change.

There might not actually be any *problem*, per se; a new program (or new version of an existing program) that can open those file types may simply have changed the icon. This isn't always desirable behavior, but it's not usually harmful.

To know what the program in question is, there are tools that will help us get it out of the registry. Try running the following commands in CMD.EXE:

```
assoc .rar
ftype <whatever was to the right of the = sign from the previous command>
```

What are the outputs of those commands? The output of the second command is the path to, and name of, the program that handles those file types and is therefore probably the one that set the icon. (In theory, the icon and the association could be set by different programs, but in practice they're pretty much always set together.)

You can change the file icons in the following ways:

- Automatically: right-click a file of the relevant type, and select `Open With...`. If necessary, then click `Choose another app`. Once the list of apps that can open the file appears, check the `Always use this app to open <extension> files` box, choose the app you want to use, and click OK. It will probably update the icon.
- Automatically: Using the search box in Start (you can just start typing into the Start menu or Start screen), find "Default Programs" and run it.

  - Click `Set your default programs` if you want to choose an app and then select file types for it.
  - Click `Associate a file type with a program` if you want to choose a file type, then choose the app it opens in.
  - Either way, you can set the file type <-> program association, which will usually change the icon.
- Semi-manually: Using either the `assoc` command or editing the registry using a tool such as `regedit`, change the file type for a given extension. You can see the list of all file types by running the `ftype` command in CMD, though it will be long. The icon is tied to the file type, which isn't necessarily tied to a specific extension (for example, both `,jpg` and `.jpeg` have the file type `jpegfile` on a default Win10 configuration). To do this change via the registry, go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, open the key for the extension in question, and change the default (un-named) string value for that key.
- Fully manually: Using a registry editor, you can directly modify the default icon for a file type. Under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, expand the file type key (not the file extension key, though you can use that to find the file type) and select the `DefaultIcon` sub-key. (If it somehow doesn't exist, you can create a sub-key called `DefaultIcon`.) Edit the default String value to by the path to the icon file (or icon resource embedded in another file, such as an EXE or DLL) that you want to see used for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is an accepted answer, will learn from mistakes if it is not.

I recently downloaded **NCH Software**... ExpressScribe.  I did not notice this until today, after 3 days, **but the exact icon images** the OP shows in their figure above was what my files looked like as well.  **I was confused**.  This SuperUser answer was the first search item on Google to show up.  Thankfully.

I followed suit, before coming here.  **This answer is for** those who right-clicked the file(s) and chose **Default Program** as WinRAR or whichever your default is for the file types that were changed without your knowledge and/or permission, ***but* where the** **icon did *NOT* change** leaving you even more confused than before!

Do not fret, I figured it out.  I went to **START** then typed **change file associations** then from the list I chose **Set Your Default Programs** and when that didn't work, I went back and chose **Set Files to Open With a Specific Program** ... and this is where I **discovered the fix**.

**Dilemma**: So, *my **actual icon** stayed the same*.  I was **confused**.  I first thought changing the "icon picture" in Windows Control Panel options would be proper but as I pondered this, I realized something.  It wouldn't have solved anything.  In **the option** window **'Set Files to Open with a Specific Program'** it gives you a 3 column list: 1. **File Type Names**; 2. **Description of the File Type**; 3. **Default Program that Opens it**.

I noticed **in all the file types opened by NCH Express Scribe**, there were strange ones I hadn't seen before... specifically ***.arw**

**The specific files** in question **where the icon stayed the same and didn't change** when I made the first fix, they **were described as "WinRAR Archive"** files.  But *other* WinRAR Archive files weren't screwed with.  They were fine.  So, **all I did** **was** guesstimate and **choose that file type *.arw** *opened with* **WinRAR *instead* of NCH ExpressScribe Software**.  To my utter surprise, **ALL** 9 **of the** leftover **files** I was fretting about **had** **SWITCHED BACK SUCCESSFULLY!**

So, I hope this helped and I will come back later to edit this answer to be less wordy, more clear and to the point.

Comment: This answer is specifically for those who used above fixes for changing back the default program but did not work, nor change the icon itself. It is specifically for *.ARW file type, however, that was the case in my own dilemma .. 

UPDATE:  This did NOT change ALL of the file types back.  Some are still unchanged and this is really confusing me.  But at least I was able to assist in some cases.

Comment: (1a) Don’t be redundant.  You say in the answer that you’re addressing the situation where the user tried to change the file association (default program), but it didn’t work (the icon didn’t change).  And then you say in the next two paragraphs that that’s what you did.  And then you repeat yourself again in a comment. (1b) You should probably be able to reduce the length of your answer by 20% without losing any valuable information.  If you realized that the answer was unnecessarily wordy (and unclear and unfocused), why did you rush to post it?  The question was asked … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  almost three years ago.  There’s nobody sitting by the terminal, waiting for an answer — another day or two wouldn’t have hurt.  (2) Focus on the technical answer.  Don’t elaborate on how confused you were, how many days it took you to notice things, or what you pondered (upon a midnight dreary). (3) I strongly urge you to remove all the bold and italics from your answer. (4) Don’t update your answer by tacking comments onto it; [edit] the answer.  In particular, don’t (boldly) claim SUCCESS in the answer, and then say in a comment that your solution didn’t really work.

Comment: P.S. When we refer to [SU], we write it as *two words* (separated by a space).